# Struts 2 - s:select using Map

Tags: jakarta-ee, select, struts2, hashmap

In struts 2 I want to use s:select populated from a Map.
My map has values like
    "key1" , "value1"
    "key2" , "value2"

Keys are what I want to be posted (which are) but it diplays values. I don't want to show the values but the value returned form a method I use in others (like s:text) getTranslation("value1") and show that value.

If I try

```
<s:select ... list="myMap" listValue="getTranslation(myMap)">
```

It doesn't show anything, just empty boxes to select. How do I get the id of the iteration to populate to select so as to use something like:

```
<s:select ... list="myMap" listValue="getTranslation(myMap.get(  how do I get this id?   ))">
```

Or something similar?

Comment: you can use `listKey` and `listValue` property of select tag.Please read http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/select.html

Comment: As I explicitly told in the question, I use listKey and listValue properties, but in listValue I do not want to show the value of the map, but the value returned by a method when I pass as a parameter the value of the map.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Rendering of

```
<s:select list="myMap" />
```

is equals to

```
<s:select list="myMap" listKey="key" listValue="value" />
```

---

then try the following

```
<s:select list="myMap" listValue="getTranslation(value)" />
```

Comment: I found it before I saw this answer and yes I confirm this is the solution! Thanks!  

    <s:select list="myMap" listKey="key" listValue="getTranslation(value)" />