# fill select in struts2

Tags: java, list, jsp, select, struts2

I am trying to fill my struts2 select with this method but all I am getting is empty 
dropdown. This is my action method

```
private List<String> districtList = new ArrayList<String>();


public String get_DistrictList(){         
    try{
        currentCon = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
        Statement stmt = (Statement) currentCon.createStatement();          
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT district_id, district_name FROM district");
        while(rs.next())                
            districtList.add(rs.getString("district_name"));
           districtList.add(rs.getString("district_id"));


    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error From DAO:" + e);
    }   
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

my jsp

```
 <s:select label="Select District" 
                   id="district_list"
                   headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select District"
                   list="districtList" listKey="district_id" listValue="district_name"
                   tooltip="Select District"        
                   name="notaryposition.district" />
```

when i used only single add in districtList & deleted listKey & listValue it was working properly but I want both key and value in my select. Is there a way?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you generate setter and getters for districtList in controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using **Map**

```
private Map<String, String> districtMap;

/**Setters and getters for Map*/

public String get_DistrictList(){   
    districtMap = new HashMap<String, String>();      
    try{
      .
      .
      .
      while(rs.next())                
        districtMap.put(rs.getString("district_name"), rs.getString("district_id"));
      .
      .
    }catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println("Error From DAO:" + e);
  }   
  return SUCCESS;
}
```

And **generate setter and getters for above Map**. And

In `JSP`

[Reference for Select using Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429804/struts-2-sselect-using-map)

```
 <s:select label="Select District" 
    id="district_list"
    headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select District"
    list="districtMap" listKey="key" listValue="value"
    tooltip="Select District"        
    name="notaryposition.district" />
```

Comment: Thank u for your reply but it gives mr this error :The requested list key 'districtMap' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609752/struts2-list-couldnt-be-resolved/19586169#19586169

Comment: Make `private Map<String, String> districtMap;` and generate setters and getters. :)

Comment: Go through this http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-sselect-drop-down-box-example/

Comment: Thank u for your time.. I did try private Map<String, String> districtMap; watching at your previous link but this is not working. And ofcos i have already searched the net also the mkyong but could not find the ans. I think instead of map ArrayList could solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this, This is way to get id,name `%{district_id} & %{district_name}`

```
private List<District> districtList = new ArrayList<District>();
try{
    ........
     District district_object=new District();  //Create Object District Class
     while(rs.next()){

            district_object.setDistrictName(rs.getString("district_name"));
            district_object.setDistrictId(rs.getString("district_id"));
            districtList.add(district_object);
                     }
     .........
   }catch(Exception e){ sout }
```

Success.jsp

```
     <s:select label="Select District" 
               id="district_list"
               headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select District"
               list="districtList" 
               listKey="%{district_id}"    
               listValue="%{district_name}"
               tooltip="Select District"        
               name="notaryposition.district" />
```

Comment: thank u for ur reply. I think this is the correct approach. I took a <s:form> and in the action called this method but the dropdown is empty. Where do we need to call the action?? so that the dropdown fills on page load